# Experience Replay Explain

Tags: deep-learning, supervised-learning, q-learning, dqn

I have read many blog articles, research papers and watched many youtube videos, but it seems it is hard to find why experience replay is efficient.

I know that the experience replay stores (state, action, reward, newstate) and sample minibatch and update weights, however, what I don't understand is how come the bellman equation can be the target value and how the learning can be done with supervised learning the value of (reward + gamma * (maximum next action)) being target?

It would be great if you can suggest any articles or videos? 
or explain it.